# Sox: mix two inputs one of them repeated

Tags: linux, audio, raspberry-pi, sox

I am trying to mix to inputs in raspberry pi using sox; one will be a repeated loop of a wav file and the other will be usb mic input output will be the speakers.
so far i got the mic and and the wav functioning:

here is my line

```
sox --combine mix -r 44100 -t alsa hw:1,0 /pathofthewavfile/ -d
```

and i loop a wav file with, for example

```
play /pathofthewavfile/ repeat 3
```

Can anyone help me with adding the repeat to the combine mix line?
I wasn't successful neither by putting it right behind the /pathofthewavfile/ nor after -d.

Thanks
Isik

Answer (score 1):

I got this working with this line:
sox -m  -r 44100 -t alsa hw:1,0  '|sox  /home/pi/music/hop.wav -p repeat 999' -d

Cheers